# Obtaining the number of the previous week in a batch file

Tags: batch

I am using the following code to get a two-digit number of the current week in a batch file.

```
 for /f "tokens=2-4 delims=/ " %%a in ('date /t') do (set mm=%%a&set dd=%%b&set yy=%%c)
 set /a dd=100%dd%%%100,mm=100%mm%%%100
 set /a z=14-mm,z/=12,y=yy+4800-z,m=mm+12*z-3,Jd=153*m+2
 set /a Jd=Jd/5+dd+y*365+y/4-y/100+y/400-32045
 set /a y=yy+4798,Jp=y*365+y/4-y/100+y/400-31738,t=Jp+3,Jp=t-t%%7
 set /a y=yy+4799,Jt=y*365+y/4-y/100+y/400-31738,t=Jt+3,Jt=t-t%%7
 set /a y=yy+4800,Jn=y*365+y/4-y/100+y/400-31738,t=Jn+3,Jn=t-t%%7
 set /a Jr=%Jp%,yn=yy-1,yn+=Jd/Jt,yn+=Jd/Jn
 if %Jd% GEQ %Jn% (set /a Jr=%Jn%) else (if %Jd% GEQ %Jt% set /a Jr=%Jt%)
 set /a diff=Jd-Jr,cw=diff/7+1,wd=diff%%7,wd+=1
 if %cw% LSS 10 set cw=0%cw%
```

However, I would like to modify the code so that a two-digit number of the previous week is shown instead.  Can you advise how I should change the code to get this result?

Answer (score 2):

You normally just would subtract one from `%cw%`,
but there are two possible pitfalls,

1. the leading zero would have the number being interpreted as octal and error out for 08/09;
2. if `%cw%` is one there is no week zero but either week 52/53 from the previous year

To overcome issue 1:

```
set /A cw=1%cw%-101
set "cw=0%cw%"
set "cw=%cw:~-2%"
```

Or replace the 2nd last lines in **your** code

```
 set /a diff=Jd-Jr,cw=diff/7+1,wd=diff%%7,wd+=1
```

with :

```
 set /a diff=Jd-Jr,cw=diff/7,wd=diff%%7,wd+=1
```

---

That could still return a cw of 00.

As your code presumably stems from [Ritchie Lawrence Batch function Library](https://ritchielawrence.github.io/batchfunctionlibrary/) the best way would be:

- get the current date in a more reliable way with either wmic or powershell.
- convert the date to a number Library function DateToMJD
- subtract 7 from that number
- convert back with Library function MJDtoDate
- finally use Library function DateToWeek which has year,week,dayofweek components.

Complying to ISO8601 the week number for days Dec 29..31/Jan 1..3 can belong to the other year, so a week number should always be combined with year.

Comment: Thanks very much, lotpings. I was provided with the code, and personally do not actually understand how it all works. As a result, could you please provide me with the complete modified code with your suggestions included in overcoming issue 1?  I am not familiar with power shell either unfortunately and need to run everything via batch files.

Comment: If you can live with issue 2 see changed answer where I remove an  increment of cw.